# Script stops when user is changed

Tags: linux, backup, sudo, postgresql

I am trying to create a script that logs as a different user to create a database backup. 
So far I have encountered a few problems, such as having to input `sudo` password, or not being able to bypass the password prompt for the PostgreSQL database credentials.

My script does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - postgres
cd /opt/app/backup
pg_dump --username=admin dbName > file.gz
```

When I run this script, it changes my local user to the `postgres` user as expected, but it does not execute the other lines until I type in `logout`. The prompt becomes stuck on:

```
-bash-4.1$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using RedHat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a preface, but why you are even running this script with `sudo` or even switching users? I assume you want it to run in the background, right? Then why not just set a cron job for the `postgres` user? Or why are you even switching to the `postgres` user at all? Why not just run the backups as your regular user? The user on the actual Linux system itself and the `postgres` database credentials are two different things you know.

That said, onto your specific question:

> When I run this script, it changes my local user to the `postgres`
>   user as expected…

Are you sure that is what happens? Is the output of [`whoami`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whoami) actually `postgres`? I say that because I am not too clear on this line:

```
sudo su - postgres
```

That `sudo su -` switches the user to the root and then the `postgres` that follows it… Unsure how the shell would handle that? In my mind it should simply be this:

```
sudo su postgres
```

Also, looking at [the answer “Barmar” provides here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758312/117259), it seems like using [“here documents”](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)—a.k.a. “here docs—might be another tact to pip commands to that user. Knowing that, here is a rewrite of your script that might work:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su postgres <<'EOF'
cd /opt/app/backup
pg_dump --username=admin dbName > file.gz
EOF
```